# Tkinter freezes with time

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm learning Tkinter and at the moment I'm making a dice rolling program, I have encountered a problem where Tkinter freezes, I don't want that to happen as I want the program to have a simple animation where a `Label` changes from a random number between 1 - 6 and eventually stops giving you the number you rolled.

Here's my code:

```
import random
import time
from tkinter import *


app = Tk()
app.title("Dice")
app.geometry("200x220")

l1 = Label(app, text=0)
l1.pack()


def randomizer():
    b = 0
    if b < 3:
        a = random.randrange(0, 7, 1)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        l1.config(text=a)
        b += 1


b1 = Button(app, text="Get New Number", command=randomizer)
b1.pack()


app.mainloop()
```

`after` method:

```
import random
from tkinter import *


app = Tk()
app.title("Dice")
app.geometry("200x220")

l1 = Label(app, text=0)
l1.pack()


def change():
    a = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
    l1.config(text=a)


def time():
    b = 0
    if b < 30:
        app.after(100, change)

        b += 1


b1 = Button(app, text="Get New Number", command=time)
b1.pack()


app.mainloop()
```

I don't know if the way I used after is correct

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep` when using `tkinter`. Look at `.after` scripts instead

Comment: Are you still using python 2.x?

Comment: @TheLizzard I'm using after but it still doesn't work

Comment: @CoolCloud im using py 3.9

Comment: @CunningBard You can't use `import Tkinter` when using python 3. You should be using `import tkinter` or `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: @CoolCloud Do you want to write an answer using `.after`?

Comment: Nah its fine, you can do it @TheLizzard

Comment: @TheLizzard the "import tkinter" became "import Tkinter" because of Grammarly

Comment: @CunningBard You should really wait before accepting answers, and accept the best one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the proper use of a loop using tkinter:

```py
import random
import tkinter as tk


app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry("200x220")

label = tk.Label(app, text="0")
label.pack()

def change(b=0):
    if b < 30:
        a = random.randrange(1, 7, 1)
        label.config(text=a)
        app.after(100, change, b+1)


b1 = tk.Button(app, text="Get New Number", command=change)
b1.pack()


app.mainloop()
```

The problem with your code is that you scheduled all of the `change` calls 100 milliseconds after the button was pressed. So it didn't work.

In the code above I use something like a for loop done using `.after` scripts. When calling a function you can add default values for the arguments like what I did here: `def change(b=0)`. So the first call to `change` is done with `b = 0`. When calling `.after` you can add parameters that will be passed when the function is called. That is why I used `b+1` in `app.after(100, change, b+1)`.

Comment: Thanks it works and i understand some of it I guess

Comment: @CunningBard I expanded the explanation. Please tell me the parts that you don't get so I can explain them better.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand the After Method with your Explanation and Answer