# Tkinter progress bar not working properly

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I am trying to add a progress bar to my window until some work is being done. But it is not working properly. I want it to keep moving until the work is done but it just moves rapidly and then stops. Also if I try to minimize or close the progress window it just hangs and stops responding.
Can anyone help me how can I do it properly? Here is my code.

```
import time
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

numbers = []

def main():
    main_window = Tk()
    app = info(main_window)
    main_window.mainloop()


class info:
    def __init__(self, root):
        # start = timer()
        self.error_str = ''
        self.root1 = root
        self.root1.title('LOADING......')
        self.root1.geometry("380x200")

        self.root1.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        self.root1.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.root1.configure(background='white')

        progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.root1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                   length=380, mode='determinate')
        progress.place(x=0, y=100)
        i = 20

        for x in range(1, 50):
            numbers.append(x * 2)
            print(numbers)

            progress['value'] = i
            self.root1.update_idletasks()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            i = i + 40

        self.root = root
        self.root.title('Second window')

        self.root.geometry('1350x800+0+0')

        frame1 = Frame(self.root, bg='#7877a5')
        frame1.place(x=0, y=0, width=1350, height=150)
        title = Label(frame1, text="Second Window", font=("Times New Roman", 40, "bold", "italic"),
                      bg='#7877a5',
                      fg='white')
        title.place(x=380, y=45)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you shouldn't call `time.sleep()` in a tkinter application because it interferes with the GUI's `mainloop()` and will make your program hang or freeze. Use the universal widget method [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) instead.

Lastly you need to specify a maximum value for the `Progressbar` so its indicator scales properly relatively to the values of `i` you are setting its value to. The default for `maximum` is only 100, which your code was greatly exceeding in the `for x` loop.

Here's the code that needs to change in `info.__init__()`. The two lines changed have `# ALL CAPS` comments:

```
        progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.root1, orient=HORIZONTAL,
                                   length=380, mode='determinate',
                                   maximum=(48*40)+20)  # ADDED ARGUMENT.
        progress.place(x=0, y=100)
        i = 20

        for x in range(1, 50):
            numbers.append(x * 2)
            print(numbers)

            progress['value'] = i
            self.root1.update_idletasks()
            self.root1.after(100)  # Delay in millisecs.  # REPLACED TIME.SLEEP() CALL.
            i = i + 40
```

Comment: I think that using `.after` without specifying a function has the same effect as `time.sleep`. Therefore, I think it should be avoided.

Comment: I think it's better to implement the `for` loop using a `tkinter` loop like what I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738164/11106801).

Comment: @TheLizzard: Using `after()` without specifying a callback function to replace `time.sleep()` is precisely *why* that argument is optional. Coding a "`tkinter` loop" like you do in the linked answer to another question is fine, too. I did it the way shown here simply because it required the fewest changes to the OP's code, which uses `range()` to control the loop — and there's nothing "improper" about doing that in a `tkinter` app (if you do it correctly).

Comment: @TheLizzard: P.S. I personally don't like using using indexing to set widget options like the OP does via `progress['value'] = i`, and instead prefer being more explicit about things by using `progress.config(value=i)`, but I left it the way it was because it's fine and shown done that way in a number of tutorials and documentation.

Comment: If someone in the future finds this answer and they use this with something higher for the delay, `tkinter` will stop responding. On my computer if I increase it to 1000 milliseconds, `tkinter` stops responding. To better see it try something like 10000 milliseconds. The approach I suggested doesn't have this issue. PS, I also don't like indexing it but sometimes it can be useful to use the `+=` operator.

Comment: @TheLizzard: I've never noticed that issue, but have seldom used delays that long. Regardless, it doesn't apply to this situation because the delay's only 0.1 second. Good point about about indexing wrt to in-place operators like `+=` — although frankly it's not something I can recall ever needing to do. Do you know of any other examples?

Comment: I just remember that I was answering someone's question recently and I saw that they used the `+=` operator. That is the only case where I have seen indexing a `tkinter` widget that actually helps. If I am programming, I would still use `progress.config(value=progress.cget("value") + ...)` instead of `+=`.

Comment: @TheLizzard: Wow, now that's what I would call explicit… Anyway—back to your original comment—using `after` without specifying a function **isn't** the same as using `time.sleep` in the sense that it's not supposed to interfere with the `mainloop` running.

Comment: [This comment (from cpython's source code)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fbc349ff790c21f1a59af939d42033470790c530/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L832) also suggests that `time.sleep` is the same as `after` (when you haven't specified the function). Also [this](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl8.0a1/after.n.html) says that: *"While the command is sleeping the application does not respond to events."*

Comment: @TheLizzard: Interesting. Well, what's in the CPython source is merely a comment—that's not what it *does*. All I can think of is that there are other things the `mainloop` does besides processing user events (such as arranging for other `after`-scheduled calls to take place or playing-nice with the OS).

Comment: [tcl's official documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/after.html) also says that *"While the command is sleeping the application does not respond to events."* Also if you want to try it out, I made a simple example [here](https://pastebin.com/t5M2ALCM). My example uses `root.after(100000)` and then `tkinter` stops responding (or handling event bindings).  I don't see how that's different to `time.sleep`

Comment: @TheLizzard: You're right, so I don't know what the difference is — yet another `tkinter` mystery I guess.