# Running a function multiple time and displaying output on tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, conways-game-of-life

I am coding 'The Game Of Life' and using tkinter as a GUI. I have a grid (just a grid of 20 by 20 Buttons), and and an 'updateGrid' function that takes the current values of the grid and updates it according to the rules of The Game Of Life. I linked the 'updateGrid' function to a 'Next' button, thus if the Next button is clicked, the grid is updated. I want to implement a 'runGrid' function, (connected to a 'Run' button) that runs the 'updateGrid' function numerous times. I've tried this:

```
def runGrid():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        updateGrid()
        time.sleep(4)
```

but it seems like the tkinter GUI only updates once the runGrid function is completed. I want the tkinter GUI to update after each iteration so that the user can see the progress of the runGrid function.

Here is a screenshot of the grid before any button is pressed:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the grid after the 'runGrid' function is executed:
[image]

The glider (the pattern) 'moves' from the first position to the last position in 10 moves, however, only the first and the last position is can be seen with the runGrid function. If the updateGrid function is called 10 times in a row, every move can be seen.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Instead of `time.sleep` use `<any tkinter widget>.after(time_delay_in_ms, <function to call>)`. For an example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738164/11106801) to see how I implemented a for loop as a `tkinter` loop

Comment: there are many examples which uses `after(milliseconds, function_name)` to execute function periodically without blocking `mainloop`.

Comment: all GUIs works different then you expect. They run your function and they wait for its end to update all widget in window in one moment. This way it has to update it only once - so it has less work - and window doesn't blinking.

Comment: @furas Not important but not all GUI's run like that. From what I remember there are no bindings/after scripts in `pygame`.

Comment: Thank you , @TheLizzard, I used the after function and it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @TheLizzard yes, probably not all GUIs work this way. Probably some modern GUIs use some new methodology to recognize when they really have to redraw widgets. As for `pygame`: I never treated it as `GUI` because it doesn't have widgets like other GUIs. It is based on library `SDL` and its full name `Simple DirectMedia Layer` describes it well - it is low-level library which needs extra code to create GUI.

Comment: @furas A GUI is a Graphical User Interface. As `pygame` helps you create a graphical interface for the user, I consider it a GUI. `pygame` is quite basic but it took me a few days to implement buttons, labels, frames, canvases, event bindings, after scripts and the grid manager as a library that only uses `pygame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When GUIs (`tkitner`, `PyQt`, other GUIs, other languages) run your function then they does't update widgets at once but they wait for end of your code and they update all widgets only once. This way they have less work and they redraw window only once so it doesn't blink.

---

You can use `after(milliseconds, function_name, [arg1, ...])` to execute function periodically without blocking `mainloop`

Something like this

```
def runGrid(i=10):
    updateGrid()
    if i > 0:
       root.after(4000, runGrid, i-1)  # 4000ms = 4s
```

---

Eventually you can use `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to redraw window

```
def runGrid():
    for i in range(0, 10):
        updateGrid()
        root.update()
        time.sleep(4)
```

Comment: The second method can cause a recursion error, if the user sends a bunch of events that call `runGrid` from the `root.update()`.

Comment: Also with the second method, moving the window becomes very choppy.