# Screen updates slowly using Tkinter Scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When I run this code and I grab the scroll bar and move it up and down quickly, the screen is very slow to load the items on the screen. Is there any way to speed up the "refresh rate" of how quickly the screen updates what is on it?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
container = tk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
row=0

for i in range(100):
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='test').grid(row=row, column=1)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='test1').grid(row=row, column=2)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random').grid(row=row, column=3)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random1').grid(row=row, column=4)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random2').grid(row=row, column=5)
    tk.Button(scrollable_frame, text='button').grid(row=row, column=6)
    row=row+1

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you creating that many widgets anyways? It's rare to need more than 100 widgets. Right now you are trying to create 600 widgets. I suggest you redesign your program. If you really need to make that many widgets use `.after()` to create them in chunks.

Comment: @TheLizzard My actual application is grabbing data from a SQL DB and presenting it to the user. Sometimes the results are long and it requires 600+ results. How would I incorporate the .after() into this so that scrolling is smoother? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a design flaw. You should never need more than 100 widgets.

But if you really need that many widgets try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
container = tk.Frame(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

def create_widgets(row:int=0) -> None:
    # If row == 100 stop the loop
    if row == 100:
        return None

    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='test').grid(row=row, column=1)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='test1').grid(row=row, column=2)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random').grid(row=row, column=3)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random1').grid(row=row, column=4)
    tk.Label(scrollable_frame, text='random2').grid(row=row, column=5)
    tk.Button(scrollable_frame, text='button').grid(row=row, column=6)

    # Change the 10 to something smaller if you want it to be faster.
    # But keep it above 3
    root.after(10, create_widgets, row+1)

create_widgets()

container.pack()
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

root.mainloop()
```

It removes the delay at the start when first creating the widgets. It uses a for loop made out of `.after` scripts. For more info please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738164/11106801).

There is no way of solving the scrolling problem that you are having. `tkinter` wasn't built to handle that many widgets.

Comment: This does seem to help the scrolling until i scroll to the bottom, then it is the same. So basically your saying that once that many widgets are loaded onto the screen there is no way to make the scrolling more fluid, at least using tkinter?

Comment: I am going to try and combine the 5 labels into 1 bigger label to limit the number of widgets tkinter has to create and display and see if that helps. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Lzypenguin Combining the labels will make it better for sure.